# Set imageview with captured image for multiple request codes

Tags: java, android

My application has 5 buttons that capture images and for each image captured in those request codes the image needs to be set to an imageview, the code only sets the image for only one of the request code? And if the second request code is pressed enter then the application stops running

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = {};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        File imgFile = new  File(capturedImageFilePath);

        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            first_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // user cancelled Image capture
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "No picture for your Schedule", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
    } else {
        // failed to capture image
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
    }
} else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE_2) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] projection = {};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String captureImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        File imgFile = new  File(captureImageFilePath);

        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            second_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `then the application stops running`. Then you will have an exception or error mentioned in the logcat. Have a look and post relevant part. Please start your sentences with a capital. This is not a chat room.